# How to regex match P tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to match this following condition using regex

```
<P ***anything here*** >
```

So essentially, I want to strip any opening P tag with any attributes. I dont want to stip anything else in the string.

Test case/

```
<p style='color: green;'>What a fine day it is</p>
```

Desired Result/

```
What a fine day it is</p>
```

Comment: Use a html parser instead, never parse html with regex.

Comment: I am not asking for conventions or correct way to do things, I am working with a system that does not allow any other tools, i MUST use regex.

Comment: What about `<p>Hello, <strong>World</strong>!</p>`? or `<p>Hello, <u>World</u>!</p>`, or when something goes wrong and you have `<p>Hello <p>World</p>!</p>`?

Comment: _"I am working with a system that does not allow any other tools, i MUST use regex"_ - then remove the jQuery tag from the question, because it's evidently not relevant, and state the restrictions you have as part of the question.

Comment: Why do you need to strip out the opening p tag completely? Are there multiple p tags in the document? Is it satisfactory to just have an opening p tag with no attributes? It seems you are [asking about your step, and not your goal](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal), having already presumed that regex matching to delete the opening p tag is the way to do this, when I can envision better options depending on your circumstances. What's your goal? To get a document with p tags and just clear out all their attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @kojiro already mentioned, this is [not a good path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), however:

```
var sample = "<p style='color:green;'>What a fine day it is</p>";
var result = sample.replace(/<p\b[^>]*>/ig,'');
// result = "What a fine day it is</p>"
```

*Obligatory Footnote* if you have an attribute that contains the `>` character within the `<p>` tag, this will fail epically. but, then again, that's why the above referenced post exists on SO. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for actually reading the answer, and answering it. It is disappointing the number of people that downvote a question just because a better solution exists, which cannot be used in this case. +100

Comment: @RafaTost: no problem. Helping (and outlining caveats) are acceptable answers, imho. as long as the OP doesn't assume anything I write is bullet-proof, we're fine. ;-)

Comment: The `\b` means this will match things like `<p->` - if that's an issue consider `<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>`